# Problems with custom resolution with amd on ubuntu 23.10

Tags: display-resolution, amd-graphics, monitor, amdgpu, 23.10

I can't get the whole screen to work so if anyone here could help me it would be great... All I need is a way for 1920x1080_73.00 to work on my monitor as a DP-1/VGA-0. Does anyone else here knows how to fix the resolution here? because I can't really work on vídeo editing at all... i'd like anyone here that could help me with this stuff because i really like vídeo editing and gaming at all...

All i tried is using ||

```
$ sudo xrandr 
cvt 1920 1080 73.00
```

without the * into it.
It worked well to this point but when I add in

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_73.00" "1920x1080_73.00"  213.25  1920 2056 2256 2592  1080 1083 1088 1129 -hsync +vsync
```

All it gives me back is:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default error message.
```

Any ideas on how to fix this error?